# MYSQL: Sorting on two fields conditionally?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores values: (actually from i18n Drupal Module)

```
nid | tnid
1   | 1
2   | 1
3   | 1
```

This effectively means that nodes 1, 2 and 3, are all derivatives of the source node, which is nid = 1. Therefore 1 = the tnid.

The problem is, you also get language neutral nodes:

```
nid | tnid
4   | 0
5   | 0
6   | 0
```

What I need, is a query to get this:

```
nid | tnid
1   | 1
4   | 0
5   | 0
6   | 0
```

in other words, group by tnid, except in the case of it being 0. What would the MySQL query for this be?

Comment: Could you expand your example and the output? What happens to NID 2 and 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE tnid = nid
   OR tnid = 0
```

Comment: I'm a dumbass. Thank you. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this. The query maps pretty cleanly to the words used to request it: "*group by tnid, except in the case of it being 0*"

You can use GROUP BY, and instead of a plain old `GROUP BY tnid`, you group by the value of a call to the "if" function.  If tnid is 0, the value produced will be unique (and therefore not group together with anything).  Otherwise, simply return the non-zero tnid.

```
select 
  min(nit), 
  if(tnid=0,concat('special',nit), tnid) 
from some_table 
group by 
  if(tnid=0,concat('special',nit), tnid);
```

Once you see why the above works, then the following is probably more like what the original request was getting after.  This also works:

```
select 
  min(nit), 
  tnid
from some_table 
group by 
  if(tnid=0,concat('special',nit), tnid);
```

Assumption Warning:

- I assumed that `nit` is like a primary key column, where each row has a unique `nit`.
- I assumed that neither `nit` nor `tnid` can be NULL.

If either of those assumptions is invalid, then the query probably needs some adjustments, but the general idea of "group by some expression" (not by a bare column) still holds.

Note:

- The rationale for concatenating 'special' with `nit` is as follows: you need something unique (hence, `nit`) to prevent the `tnid=0` rows from grouping together.  But you also need to morph the value (hence, 'special') so that it cannot be anything that would coincide with any of the actual `tnid` values from rows where `tnid` is not zero.

---

The complete example that I tested with is as follows.

I am using MySQL 5.6.26, on mac osx10.8 (x86_64), installed with Homebrew.

```
mysql> create table some_table( nit int not null, tnid int not null );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into some_table  values ( 1, 1 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into some_table  values ( 2, 1 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into some_table  values ( 3, 1 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into some_table  values ( 4, 0 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into some_table  values ( 5, 0 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into some_table  values ( 6, 0 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>     select 
    ->       min(nit), 
    ->       if(tnid=0,concat('special',nit), tnid) 
    ->     from some_table 
    ->     group by 
    ->       if(tnid=0,concat('special',nit), tnid);
+----------+----------------------------------------+
| min(nit) | if(tnid=0,concat('special',nit), tnid) |
+----------+----------------------------------------+
|        1 | 1                                      |
|        4 | special4                               |
|        5 | special5                               |
|        6 | special6                               |
+----------+----------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```